# C# DataSet To Xml, Node Rename

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

```
    DataSet ds = GetExcelToXml("test.xls");

    string filename = @"C:\test.xml";

    FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);

    XmlTextWriter myXmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(myFileStream, Encoding.Default);

    ds.WriteXml(myXmlWriter);

    myXmlWriter.Close();
```

---

Output Xml

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <UserName>bla1</User_Name>
    <Mail>bla1@bla2.com</Mail>
    <Address>World</Address>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

---

I need Xml Node Name

```
    <ROWS>
      <ROW>
        <UserName>bla1</User_Name>
        <Mail>bla1@bla2.com</Mail>
        <Address>World</Address>
      </ROW>
    </ROWS>
```

How To Make ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this,

```
ds.DataSetName = "ROWS";
ds.Tables[0].TableName = "ROW";
ds.WriteXml(myXmlWriter);
myXmlWriter.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlDocument myXml;

myXml.Load(myXmlWriter); //Not sure if this will work, but you get the idea

myXml.InnerXml = myXml.InnerXml.Replace("< NewDataSet", "< ROWS")
    .Replace("< /NewDataSet>", "< /ROWS>")
    .Replace("< Table", "< ROW")
    .Replace("< /Table>", "< /ROW>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample C# application which will read the input XML and then copy different XML/Data tables to other files using the Table name:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataSet dsXml = new DataSet();
        dsXml.ReadXml("mydata.xml");
        for (int i = 0; i < dsXml.Tables.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Table Name: " + dsXml.Tables[i].TableName);
            DataSet newDataSet = new DataSet();
            newDataSet.Tables.Add(dsXml.Tables[i].Copy());
            FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(dsXml.Tables[i].TableName + ".xml", FileMode.Create);
            XmlTextWriter myXmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(myFileStream, Encoding.Default);
            newDataSet.WriteXml(myXmlWriter);
            myXmlWriter.Close();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes here looking for the opposite direction problem where a typed dataset table name has changed since the xml files were written.

```
// for xml files created prior to rename of Sample table to SampleS, 
// rename the Sample table, read xml, 
// then rename table back to current SampleS
if (ds.SampleS.Count == 0)
{
    ds = new AnalysisDSX();
    ds.Tables["SampleS"].TableName = "Sample";
    ds.ReadXml(xmlFilePath);
    ds.Tables["Sample"].TableName = "SampleS";
}
```